# error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed

Tags: c++

I'm getting an error on Line 266.

> WorldSession.h(266): error C4430: missing type specifier - int
>   assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
> WorldSession.h(266):
>   error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not
>   support default-int

These are the two errors that I get from Visual C++ Studio 2010.

```
extern OpcodeHandler WorldPacketHandlers[NUM_MSG_TYPES];
void CapitalizeString(string & arg);
```

The first one is line 266; The second line is 267. I'm not sure what is the problem as I'm confused. Could anyone help out, thanks!

Comment: why a ; in the middle of 266?

Comment: What I told yzt below, I added that semicolon there because I kept getting an error says I was missing a semicolon to the left of WorldPacketHandlers. I know I'm confused why its there.

Comment: Post a complete example that exhibits the error.

Comment: Do you have any macros that redefine `OpcodeHandler`?

Comment: My project is really big with over at least 700 files. Not sure about that.

Comment: @user1797587: As I wrote in the comments below my answer, the original error is because the compiler doesn't know what `OpcodeHandler` is. If you are using an IDE, one easy way of finding out what the compiler may know about your type is just to hover you mouse over it. (Of course, this doesn't not always work or give you correct information, but I somehow doubt that yours is the one in 1000 case that the IDE can't parse the code correctly.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
extern OpcodeHandler; WorldPacketHandlers[NUM_MSG_TYPES];
```

should probably be

```
extern OpcodeHandler /*no semicolon here*/ WorldPacketHandlers[NUM_MSG_TYPES];
```

Comment: I added that semicolon there because I kept getting an error says I was missing a semicolon to the left of WorldPacketHandlers.

Comment: @user1797587 that error usually means that one of your .cpp or .h files isn't properly divided into blocks i.e. missing a `}` somewhere.

Comment: @Alexandru Barbarosie, no other file is included on this header file. I also tripled check to make sure I was not missing a }.

Comment: So why would you have `extern` then?

Comment: @user1797587: And the problem could be in a header that a cpp file includes before this one. You need to post more of your code and a better error report, e.g. in what source file does this happen.

Comment: @user1797587: BTW, the original error you mention means that the compiler doesn't know what `OpcodeHandler` is, i.e., you need to declare it or include the header that does declare it.

Comment: Okay I'll find out where it is; I know for sure its delcared. Thank you for your time